# How to manage chromedriver for Python and Selenium desktop application

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver

How to manage chromedriver and Chrome browser on user's computer for a browser automation desktop application built using Python and Selenium?

I have created a web application that uses Python and Selenium to login to some website and get information from there. The script works well on server because I can manage Google Chrome and chromedriver on server.
I want to replicate this functionality to desktop app, where user will install the application on desktop and can collect data from website. But, I am not sure how to handle Google Chrome and chromedriver installation on the user's computer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an executable file using [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) on your computer then place the executable file where the end users' computer can get to it.  This way the user doesn't need the Chromedriver.  If your application is just pointing to the location of Chromedriver, put the executable and Chromedriver together in a folder & put it on the network or on the user's pc.

Answer (score 1):

[SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) comes with a very customizable driver manager that can be used either directly, or via context manager (which closes the driver after the `with` block ends):

After `pip install seleniumbase`, you can run the following scripts with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)
driver.get("https://seleniumbase.github.io/")
driver.quit()
```

and via context manager:

```py
from seleniumbase import DriverContext

with DriverContext(browser="chrome", headless=False) as driver:
    driver.get("https://seleniumbase.github.io/")
```

This can be incorporated into Desktop Apps (the SeleniumBase GitHub has examples with TKinter). Also works with PyInstaller for generating executables.

For all available options, eg: `headless`, `incognito`, `locale_code`, `proxy`, etc, see [seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py)

Answer (score 0):

Use **ChromeDriverManager**. With it, you can automatically download and install the appropriate ChromeDriver version based on your system and Chrome browser version. It works for Firefox and other browsers.
It is super easy and practical :)

Code example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Initialize ChromeDriver using ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Use the driver for automation
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```